# Mongodb $in query, on a replicaSet with slaveOkay()

Tags: mongodb, replication

I'd like to know something : when we do a $in request in a replica-set environnement with slaveOkay() enabled on the driver (which is if I understood correctly basically splitting queries on the different slaves), is mongo natively splitting the $in array between slaves? Thanks by advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd have to say no.  For it to effectively split the $in array between slaves they'd have to be split before sending the query (the client/driver would need to change the query into multiple queries effectively) and merged them back for the full result.

With slaveOk it just routes the *whole* query to one member, where the first choice would be a secondary/non-primary.

If you want to (potentially) break this up across multiple servers then you could group the $in array into smaller chunks and do multiple concurrent queries.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I thought also!